# how to find the repeated elements in array using crcw pram

Tags: c

The array A contains integers in the range [1, n]. 
The problem is to decide whether there are any repeated elements in A. Show how you do this in O(1) time on an n-processor CRCW PRAM

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: @mbschenkel Hi, I am trying to tackle this problem but can't find a solution. My initial idea was to use a hashmap as the search and insertion is O(1) time. I planned to check if the array index A[i] was in the hashmap, if it was then we've got a duplicate and if not then to add it to the hash map. Would this work or are there any better ways? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to AKL Text book as per Professor said .